# Why is my Visual Studio text editor font all bold now?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I must have hit a hot key or something and I can't figure out how to undo it now. All of my text in my text editor appears to be bold. For example:

[image]

[image]

Here is a comparison from the sample in Tools > Options vs what I am seeing in my editor:

[image]

I found this setting in my Tools > Options, but it doesn't seem to change anything when ticked on or off:

[image]

How do I fix this madness?

Comment: unused "Usings" are normally greyed Out. Check if highlighted ones are being used in the file.

Comment: It's not the using highlights I am referring to. The font is actually bolder everywhere in the text editor. Let me try to update the question with some more screenshots.

Comment: @kspearrin did you tried using default ?

Comment: Have you zoomed out one too many? makes the text bold at less than 100%

Comment: I have tries the "Use Defaults" button. It didn't change anything. I have also tried zooming in and out and the boldness appears on all levels.

Comment: Wow. Nevermind. You were right. It was the zoom level. @AdamWilson. I was trying to adjust the zoom level using the mouse wheel and it never went back to a true 100%. When I manually adjusted it using the dropdown at the bottom of the editor window to 100% it looks fine now.

Comment: No problem, i do it all the time by mistake.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution that **kspearrin** mentioned in the comments section solved the problem for me:

> I was trying to adjust the zoom level using the mouse wheel and it never went back to a true 100%. When I manually adjusted it using the dropdown at the bottom of the editor window to 100% it looks fine now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem because zoom value was set to 98%.

Solved when I set it to 100% manually.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/2ijW032cgTnU.png))</sub>

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust font size from Mouse scroll down by pressing CTRL. When You're adjusting font size into smaller, one point you will notice font bold has disappeared. Then Try to change your font size into 11 and Press OK. Then change again into your preferred size 10.

Hope This could be helpful.